# Javascript is not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page referencing a jQuery page which just console logs `hello there`, but the code in the jQuery page is not doing anything and I don't know why.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    {{{body}}}
    <p>hello there you idiot</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript>" src="javascripts/testscript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
$(function(){
    //alert("hello there");
    console.log("hello there");
    document.write("hello there");
});
```

Can anyone please tell me why the script is not console loging anything. Thank you

Comment: wrap in `doucment ready` ?

Comment: Is your jquery/testscript where you think they are?  In the console under 'Network' or 'Sources' (depending on browser etc) you will see an error if they are not loading.  Also check with, in the console window, enter, simply `$` and see if it's defined

Comment: @guradio it already is

Comment: Make sure you have included jQuery from the correct path

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you've put the `>` in the wrong place in the second `<script>` tag

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like you're invoking your function. Replace `});` with `}());` or `})();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Probably**, because you're including the file wrong way (you have a typo).

The right way should be:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/testscript.js"></script>`

Comment: you're right, thanx

Comment: you're welcome. you can accept the answer.

Comment: How does this fix the issue? When does the function get run?

Comment: `$` (same as `jQuery`) will run the function when the page has fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(function(){
    //alert("hello there");
    console.log("hello there");
    document.write("hello there");
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

your function is not triggered by any event; either trigger it in an event or wrap it in document.ready like guradio suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You are including the js wrong.

```js
$(function(){
    //alert("hello there");
    console.log("hello there");
    document.write("hello there");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    {{{body}}}
    <p>hello there you idiot</p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript>" src="javascripts/testscript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Invalid `script` tag.

Instead of

`<script type="text/javascript>" src="javascripts/testscript.js"></script>`

use

`<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/testscript.js"></script>`.

Notice that there is not > after "text/javascript". A simple misspelling.